# symbol not found in source insight

Tags: php, c, source-insight

I build the project php internal source code with source insight.When I read the code in "zend.h" like this

```
typedef struct {
    zend_error_handling_t  handling;
    zend_class_entry       *exception;
    zval                   *user_handler;
} zend_error_handling;`
```

I want to use the"jump to the definition" to look up the `zend_class_entry`,But it tells me that "symbol not found". Actually it's not true. The definition of the `zend_class_entry` is in the file `zend.h` as the following:

```
typedef struct _zend_class_entry zend_class_entry;

....

struct _zend_class_entry {
char type;
char *name;
zend_uint name_length;
struct _zend_class_entry *parent;
int refcount;
zend_bool constants_updated;
zend_uint ce_flags;

HashTable function_table;
HashTable default_properties;
HashTable properties_info;
HashTable default_static_members;
HashTable *static_members;
HashTable constants_table;
const struct _zend_function_entry *builtin_functions;

union _zend_function *constructor;
union _zend_function *destructor;
union _zend_function *clone;
union _zend_function *__get;
union _zend_function *__set;
union _zend_function *__unset;
union _zend_function *__isset;
union _zend_function *__call;
union _zend_function *__callstatic;
union _zend_function *__tostring;
union _zend_function *serialize_func;
union _zend_function *unserialize_func;

zend_class_iterator_funcs iterator_funcs;

/* handlers */
zend_object_value (*create_object)(zend_class_entry *class_type TSRMLS_DC);
zend_object_iterator *(*get_iterator)(zend_class_entry *ce, zval *object, int by_ref TSRMLS_DC);
int (*interface_gets_implemented)(zend_class_entry *iface, zend_class_entry *class_type TSRMLS_DC); /* a class implements this interface */
union _zend_function *(*get_static_method)(zend_class_entry *ce, char* method, int method_len TSRMLS_DC);

/* serializer callbacks */
int (*serialize)(zval *object, unsigned char **buffer, zend_uint *buf_len, zend_serialize_data *data TSRMLS_DC);
int (*unserialize)(zval **object, zend_class_entry *ce, const unsigned char *buf, zend_uint buf_len, zend_unserialize_data *data TSRMLS_DC);

zend_class_entry **interfaces;
zend_uint num_interfaces;

char *filename;
zend_uint line_start;
zend_uint line_end;
char *doc_comment;
zend_uint doc_comment_len;

struct _zend_module_entry *module;
};
```

Same the with the `zval`.I am so confused, somebody can help me ? -_- thanks.

Comment: `zend_class_entry` must be defined before `zend_error_handling`.